# Where can I find good topographical maps of Peru?

Tags: trekking, topographical-maps, andes, peru

Disclaimer: I'm not even sure if this is an appropriate question for this forum, but I lack the requisite reputation to ask for a judgement call on meta.

I'm in the very early stages of planning a journey through Peru. My thinking so far takes two assumptions. Firstly, I'll be alone. Secondly, I'll be on foot unless I absolutely need to get somewhere quickly. With that in mind, I'm running into the following questions:

- Where can I find good topographical maps of Peru, preferably an atlas that covers all of Peru's regions?

Comment: Welcome Alex; your question would probably be easier to answer if split into three separate questions.

Comment: I have no problem with doing that, but thought it might be considered spamming.

Comment: @AlexClough nope. The stack exchange network is all about small manageable chunks so we can give you really good answers.

Comment: Since you've already asked the [second bullet as a separate question](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/13177/is-it-feasible-to-plot-my-own-trekking-route-from-lima-to-cusco), perhaps you could remove it from this post?

Comment: I still feel like this needs to be two questions. One on maps one on food

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The University of Texas Library has some decent 1:100,000 topo maps of Peru for free download:

http://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/topo/peru/

[Sample (Machupicchu):](http://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/topo/peru/santa_teresa-2344-100k.pdf)

[image]

Comment: The TF Outdoors layer on CalTopo also looks good (the Inca Trail is marked on it), and I believe it's based largely on OpenStreetMap data.

Comment: Just a quick note: 1:100'000 is **insufficient** for planning mountain treks, especially in areas like the Andes where some paths aren't clearly marked and the terrain is difficult and exposed!